# Enviar formulario sem atualizar a pagina e mostrar div oculta

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom galera eu tenho um formulário que salva os dados no banco e funciona certinho , mas preciso que ao clicar em enviar no formulário apareça uma `div` oculta com a lista dos dados salvos no banco (ja tenho a lista certinho) meu grande problema mesmo e a `div` aparecer assim que enviar o formulário sem atualizar a pagina , já tentei alguns códigos em JavaScript e jQuery que não deram certo. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Esse eo formulario para inserir os dados :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="meufrm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>

    <legend style="color: #ffffff" class="btn btn-inverse">Cadastro </legend>



    <label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>Nº da Venda :</strong> </label>
    <input type="number" name="num_venda"></br></br>


    <div id="datavenda">
        <label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>Data :</strong> </label>
        <input type="date" name="data_venda"></br></br>
    </div>


    <div id="placavenda">
        <label for="nome1" style="color: #000"><strong>Placa :</strong> </label>
        <input type="text"  name="placa" ></br></br>
    </div>

    <div id="kmvenda">
        <label for="imagem" style="color: #000"><strong>KM : </strong></label>
        <input type="number"  name="km"></br></br>
    </div>

    <?php

    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

    //escolher a base de dados
    mysql_select_db('mecanica');
    $query='Select * from produtos';

    ?>



    <label for="produtos" style="color: #000"><strong>Produto : </strong></label>
    <select name="produtos">
        <?php

        $resultado=mysql_query($query);

        while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
        { 

            echo '<option  value="' . $linha['id_produto'] . '">' . $linha['produtos'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>

    </select><br><br>


    <div id="servicovenda">
        <?php
        mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');


        mysql_select_db('mecanica');

        $query='Select * from servicos';

        ?>



        <label for="servicos" style="color: #000"><strong>Serviços : </strong></label>
        <select name="servicos">
            <?php

            $resultado=mysql_query($query);


            while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
            {

                echo '<option  value="' . $linha['id_servico'] . '">' . $linha['servicos'] . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </select><br><br>
    </div>

           <div id="enviarvenda">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Enviar" name="send" >

        <a href="listadevendas.php" class="btn btn-inverse" >Cancelar</a>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

e assim que eu enviasse os dados eu teria q lista os resultados da div oculta na mesma pagina

Comment: Publique o código até onde você tem pronto para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Recomendo que você dê uma lida nessa pergunta: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: A forma de fazer o que pretende, é através de requisição ajax, usando JavaScript: controle de objeto JSON, manipulação de DOM. Recomendo que você estude um pouco mais sobre o assunto, antes de sair pegando código aleatoriamente. A biblioteca jQuery tem algumas facilidades neste sentido.

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada sobre jQuery entao , obg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aconselho enviar os dados para o *server-side* via [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), assim você controlar melhor o comportamento da sua página, e não dá aquele *reload* chato com o `submit` do formulario.

```
$('#divOculta').hide();
function salvarExemplo(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php", //Form que recebe o "submit"
    data: {id:1,nome:'Ragnar'} //Aqui vai seus parametros
  }).success(function(data) {
    $('#divOculta').html(data.lista); //Aqui vc recebe o retorno e monta sua lista na div oculta

    //Caso queira mostrar a div oculta.
    $('#divOculta').show();

  });
}
```

<sub>Ajax é o caminho da força, aprenda a usar e respeitar a força. ;-)</sub>

Comment: Tentei assim mas tbm nao deu ;/

Comment: @Matheus, pode tentar com mais *força*, porquê a solução é por esse caminho mesmo ;) Se tiver dúvida com seu código Ajax abra outra pergunta, mas, ***por favor***, confira o guia [ask] primeiro.